# Blank page when offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

When I'm going to offline I'm able to see only a blank page. I've been trying to delete manifest from offline.html but that haven't worked. I think that I wrote something wrong in offline.html. But I do not know what. Help me. What have I done wrong?

https://thirsty-hopper-b0ad0a.netlify.app/

#serviceworker.js

```js
const CACHE_NAME = "version-1";
const urlsToCache = [ 'index.html', 'offline.html' ];

const self = this;

// Install SW
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then((cache) => {
                console.log('Opened cache');

                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
    )
});

// Listen for requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(() => {
                return fetch(event.request) 
                    .catch(() => caches.match('offline.html'))
            })
    )
});

// Activate the SW
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    const cacheWhitelist = [];
    cacheWhitelist.push(CACHE_NAME);

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
                if(!cacheWhitelist.includes(cacheName)) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }
            })
        ))
            
    )
});
```

#manifest.json

```js
{
  "short_name": "Pizza Joint",
  "name": "Pizza Joint",
  "icons": [
      {
      "src":"./icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes":"192x192",
      "type":"image/png"
  },{
      "src":"./icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes":"512x512",
      "type":"image/png"
  },{
      "src":"./icons/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "sizes":"180x180",
      "type":"image/png"
  },{
      "src":"./icons/favicon-16x16.png",
      "sizes":"16x16",
      "type":"image/png"
  },{
      "src":"./icons/favicon-32x32.png",
      "sizes":"32x32",
      "type":"image/png"
  }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#161616",
  "background_color": "#161616"
}
```

#index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./icons/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#161616" />
    <meta name="description" content="Best app for ordering your favorite pizza" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./icons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />  

    <title>Pizza Joint</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('./serviceworker.js')
            .then((reg) => console.log('Success: ', reg.scope))
            .catch((err) => console.log('Failure: ', err));
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#offline.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./icons/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#161616" />
    <meta name="description" content="Best app for ordering your favorite pizza" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./icons/apple-touch-icon.png" /> 
    
    <title>Pizza Joint</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
   
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('./serviceworker.js')
            .then((reg) => console.log('Success: ', reg.scope))
            .catch((err) => console.log('Failure: ', err));
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: github repo https://github.com/Governnment/react

Comment: Are you testing on a machine/device that you tested with during development? If so, perhaps try on another device to rule out something still in the cache of the browser.

Comment: I've been testing on my mobile then on PC. I've cleaned the cash everywhere as well. I'm just getting a blank page. No matter what. Maybe I got a problem with offline.html template. I just copied it from index.html. Could you check my code?

Comment: @Mathias This is network in chrome
[link]https://ibb.co/PrDRPHV

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints. Looks like there are some issues you need to fix to make it a valid PWA. ( [link]ibb.co/PrDRPHV )

Comment: add some content too the page. Do you see it then? RIght now you do not have any content (text, images) that will be rendered. Just the markup. If you can inspect the markup and see what you are sharing above then you are getting exactly what you provided the browser.

Comment: I just copy index.html file and create offline.html. Is it right? Or I can't render react app when I'm offline and I should write some html and css right in offline.html instead just copy from index.html? If that's what you implying then It's no use in my case 'cause I need my react app working online and offline with the same functionality